# how to configure wifi routers to walk seemlessly around large property

Tags: wireless-networking, router, ipad

How do I make all my different routers the same network?  I have great coverage with an ethernet cable (150ft) to another router down the hill to my shop.  So I'm getting great wifi coverage...but it's all different networks and I want to walk seemlessly to my shop and back with my ipad and not lose netflix connection as I walk.  It loses 1st router about half way down the hill and picks up the shops wi-fi and sometimes I'm seeing all of the networks of mine on the same ipad for choice.  Can I make some choices of ip addresses or same name or whatever I have to do I will do it. If anyones need to know my equipment both routers are dual band.  linksys AE6900, linksys EA6500 and router/modem is linksys X2000.  I'm tired of trying to figure this out on my own.

Answer (score 2):

Configure all the routers to the same SSID (wireless network name), encryption mode, and key. Use different channels, if possible. Connect the routers LAN-to-LAN, ideally connecting all the routers back to the same router rather than forming a long line. Ideally, the router all the other routers are connected to would be the one that has the Internet connection and is the DHCP server.

Comment: wow, should have come here first!  "connecting all the routers back to the same router" ...like a spider and legs?...the body is the router connected to the internet and the legs are ethernet cables and on the end of the legs could be a router?  Same SSID...wep2personal or whatever and Key ...looking for something called a Key...what is "key"?  Neither router nor modem has "key" got another name for it?...thanks soooo much!

Comment: The "key" is the encryption key, the passoword or whatever that you use to connect to the WiFi network.

Comment: found out what key is...password to access wifi network....awesome

Comment: sorry, didnt see your answer!